# Swift vs ObjC initialisation process?

Tags: ios, swift

In ObjectiveC we create objects like

```
 -(instancetype)init()
{
  return [super init]; // Here it returns initialised value
}  

Class *obj =   [[Class alloc]init]
```

But swift initialiser wont return any value.

[From Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_265)

> Unlike Objective-C initializers, Swift initializers do not return a value. Their primary role is to ensure that new instances of a type are correctly initialized before they are used for the first time.

```
init()
{
  super.init()
}  

let obj = Class()
```

Now how swift initialiser returns the instance to variable `obj`?.

How the ***allocation and initialisation*** occurs in swift?

Comment: Have Apple not released any basic Swift tutorials?

Comment: I couldnt find it in the docs

Comment: There is a book on iBooks, release by Apple and announced in the WWDC sessions and also on the developer website, that explains all of this. You should read it.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes i know about swift iBook. I have read it but i couldn't find more details about process of object allocation and initialisation. However they are talking about initialisers. Could you please answer if you know

Comment: @Anil what are you asking though? How to create an object? Swift != Objective-

Comment: Inorder to creating an instance in swift, we just call the initialiser of the class and initialiser doesnt return any value also. then how the actual instance is being return to the caller?

Comment: @Anil I really don't understand what you're asking. To create an object in swift you use `var object = MyClass()`.

Comment: isn't that good enough answer to your question (quoted from your post): _"Their primary role is to ensure that new instances of a type are correctly initialized before they are used for the first time."_? what else do you like to know about instantiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a convention. Swift initialiser sets up a valid instance and could not theoretically return anything other that a valid instance, so there's no point in explicit return.

So (from my point of view) allocation & initialisation sequence looks like this:

1. Runtime allocates instance of requested class
2. Initializer is called with `self` set to allocated instance
3. Initializer performs setup
4. Runtime returns initialised instance to client code

Although this approach breaks some useful Objective-C patterns like initialisers returning `nil` on error, the guarantee that instantiation always succeeds allows compiler to perform some optimisations. Also without dropping initialisers returning `nil` it would be impossible to actually remove `nil` from language, it would seem weird if initialisers were returning optionals.

Comment: This Objective-C pattern was not only useful, it was also a source of subtle issues. That it's gone, is a good thing, IMHO. Now, Swift introduces another problem: programmers need to learn, that failure in the init method should abort the program, preferable with using assert. There´s no way to shift responsibility to the call-site anymore ;)

Comment: Initializers from Objective-C imported into Swift actually *can* return `nil`. And since Swift classes can subclass Objective-C classes, that means Swift initializers can also effectively return `nil` (if the superclass initializer returns `nil`).

Answer (score 2):

As @NikolayKasyanov says, with the init family of initialisers, the return (of `self`) is implicit, and you can't return `nil`. However, if you want to initialise an optional that *could* return `nil`, use a class function. EG:

```
class NumberLessThan5: Int {

    var myNumber: Int
    init (i: Int) {
        self.myNumber = i
    }
    class func createWithInt(i: Int) -> NumberLessThan5? {
        if i < 5 {
            return NumberLessThan5(i)
        } else {
            return nil
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: An initializer from Objective-C imported into Swift *can* return `nil`. And since Swift classes can subclass Objective-C classes, that means Swift initializers can also effectively return `nil` (if the superclass initializer returns `nil`).

Answer (score 1):

Initialisers **DO NOT return any value explicitly** because it's not called directly by the code(actually it returns a value which is opaque to user ).

Initialisers are invoked by memory allocation and object initialization code in the runtime, on creating a new instance for a particular type (type- struct or class).Runtime uses variable's type data generated by the compiler to determine how much space is required to store an object instance in memory.

After this space is allocated, the initialiser is called as an internal part of initialisation process to initialise the contents of the fields. Then, when the initialiser exits, the runtime returns the newly-created instance.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: There isn't any direct reference to this.The swift language guide refers to "constructors" in Java as initialisers. Its just the naming convention but internal implementation is rather similar.