# Converting Objective-C init to Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How do I convert an Objective-C init to Swift? I was looking at:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

How do I convert it to `Swift`???

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858500/swift-vs-objc-initialisation-process?rq=1  Learn Swift by reading the Apple-supplied free e-book on Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no exact equivalent to this in Swift, but the place for any initialisation is the init method, which looks like this (but doesn't return anything)

```
init() {

}
```

Edit: Please learn the basics of Swift before you ask. This is very very basic stuff.

Comment: Thank you very much, just my code is wrong